# How can I solve the 403 forbidden error for my SteamWork's publisher key?

Tags: node.js, fetch, key, steam, steamworks-api

I'm attempting to use the steam web API to get inventory details from a user's steam ID in my database. The problem is that I'm attempting to use my SteamWork's publisher key and I receive the error below.

`<html><head><title>Forbidden</title></head><body><h1>Forbidden</h1>Access is denied. Retrying will not help. Please verify your <pre>key=</pre> parameter.</body></html>`

So I understand that this error essentially means that the server understands my request but I am forbidden and therefore refused authorization. The part that puzzles me is why.

[IInventory Service](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/webapi/IInventoryService) I'm using the GetInventory method, which is marked as a partner API.

I have tested with different keys, and different applications and keys and get the same response. The key is formatted correctly and are active at the time of running.

Here is my request here below,

`const response = await fetch(`https://partner.steam-api.com/IInventoryService/GetInventory/v1/?key=${process.env.STEAMAPI}&appid=${appId}&steamid=${steamId}`);`

I'm fairly new to working in this context, so if any extra information is relevant so that I can rectify feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You need to confirm that the API key you are using is under the currently accessed domain name, as Steam has a whitelist